# Why I failed to get cookies?

Tags: vb.net, internet-explorer, cookies

I want to get cookies from internet explorer. So I follow a code from the web. I login to a site, say bodis.com and then I tried to read cookies

```
Private Declare Function InternetGetCookieEx Lib "wininet.dll" Alias "InternetGetCookieExA" (url As String, cookieName As String, cookieData As System.Text.StringBuilder, ByRef size As Integer, dwFlags As Int32, lpReserved As IntPtr) As Boolean
Private Const InternetCookieHttponly As Int32 = &H2000

Public Function GetUriCookieContainer1(uri As Uri) As System.Net.CookieContainer
    Dim cookies As System.Net.CookieContainer = Nothing
    ' Determine the size of the cookie
    Dim datasize As Integer = 8192 * 16
    Dim cookieData As New System.Text.StringBuilder(datasize)
    Dim sURL = uri.ToString
    sURL = "http://google.com" ' for simplicity sake
    If Not InternetGetCookieEx(sURL, Nothing, cookieData, datasize, InternetCookieHttponly, IntPtr.Zero) Then
        If datasize < 0 Then 'always return 0 even though I am sure there is cookies
            Return Nothing
        End If
```

...

Why datasize is always 0. I know there is cookies. I put sURL="http://google.com" to make sure everybody understand I want google.com cookies. I already login to google.com and there is indeed cookies.

I tried a bunch of other sites. http://bodis.com http://www.bodis.com and other things. None works.

Comment: This isn't objective-c, looks more like VB.

Comment: sorry. Yes its vb.net. Thanks for correction. I used to ask objective-c question.